# Cannot start Plone production instances normally with plone.app.async enabled

Tags: plone

After adding plone.app.async, I cannot start my production instances normally using 'bin/instance start'. However, the instances run fine using 'foreground' and I can start the production instances on my development machine just fine. (The machines have almost identical configurations but the production machine has almost 100GB of data in blob storage.)

Additionally, I can start the instances normally if I remove support for plane.app.async, specifically the zcml-additions section, from my buildout. And I can start the worker instance for plone.app.async just fine. It uses almost all the same sections as the regular instances except for 'zcml-additional' being for worker instead of instance.

This happens with both single and multi db for plone.app.async.

---

The instance log shows that it gets trapped in some sort of cycle during startup. Here is the log of what happens:

```
....
2012-02-09T18:31:27 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Thu Feb  9 18:31:27 2012
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8081
2012-02-09T18:31:32 INFO ZServer WebDAV server started at Thu Feb  9 18:31:32 2012
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 1980
2012-02-09T18:31:32 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone"
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage ClientStorage (pid=16331) created RW/normal for storage: '1'
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.cache created temporary cache file '<fdopen>'
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Testing connection <ManagedClientConnection ('127.0.0.1', 8100)>
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.zrpc.Connection(C) (127.0.0.1:8100) received handshake 'Z3101'
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Server authentication protocol None
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Connected to storage: ('localhost', 8100)
2012-02-09T18:31:34 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage No verification necessary -- empty cache
2012-02-09T18:31:45 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Thu Feb  9 18:31:45 2012
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8081
2012-02-09T18:31:50 INFO ZServer WebDAV server started at Thu Feb  9 18:31:50 2012
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 1980
....
```

This repeats forever.

---

With a logging level of debug, I receive the following output: http://pastebin.com/nnyekuRA 
Around line 58 is what I think is the culprit:

```
2012-02-09T17:18:22 DEBUG ZEO.ClientStorage pickled inval None '\x03\x94X\x8a\xa8\xe9\xf6\xee'
------
2012-02-09T17:18:22 BLATHER ZEO.zrpc (15892) CM.connect_done(preferred=1)
------
2012-02-09T17:18:22 BLATHER ZEO.zrpc (15892) CT: exiting thread: Connect([(2, ('127.0.0.1', 8100))])
```

But I have no idea why this is happening or even if this is correct.

---

Here is the buildout for deployment:
http://pastebin.com/u8D7swJs

Comment: Could you paste your configuration also?

Comment: yeah, buildout sections would be useful. Also, a 100GB man? Don't even think about single-db.

Comment: 100 GB sounds like you want to look into blob storage and relstorage with some urgency. :-)

Comment: Ok, I added the buildout cfg. Also, the 100GB of data is in blob storage. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions were set incorrectly on the Plone 'parts' directory. This prevented 'uuid.txt' from being written in 'parts/instance/' . There were no error messages to indicate this problem.